# Latest apacheignite/web-agent:2.7.0/2.6.0 (BOTH) is giving the error "older version of the agent" and Failed to find agent property file

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am using Latest apacheignite/web-agent:2.7.0 image and that is giving  "the older version of the agent" and "Failed to find agent property file" error.

````
[2019-07-28 05:36:48,622][WARN ][main][AgentLauncher] **Failed to find agent property file: default.properties**
 Agent configuration:
User's security tokens          : ****************abcb
URI to Ignite node REST server  : http://10.x.y.z:8080
URI to Ignite Console server    : http://frontend.web-console.svc.cluster.local
Path to agent property file     : default.properties
Path to JDBC drivers folder     : ./jdbc-drivers
Demo mode                       : enabled
 [2019-07-28 05:36:49,727][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Connecting to: http://frontend.web-console.svc.cluster.local
[2019-07-28 05:36:50,211][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connection established.
[2019-07-28 05:36:50,319][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] **You are using an older version of the agent. Please reload agent**```

Please check "web-console-deployment.yaml" under this URL https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation
````

Answer (score 0):

Please use `console.gridgain.com` for now. Apache Ignite and/or GridGain will roll our a solution soon.